# replace \N with math.nan in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

| tconst | ordering | nconst | category | job | Characters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tt0069049 | 10.0 | nm0613657 | editor | \N | \N |
| tt0069049 | 1.0 | nm0001379 | actor | \N| | ["Jake Hannaford"] |

I have the above dataset in a csv file, I've loaded the dataset using pandas and I'm trying to replace the \N vals with math.nan (using the math and pandas libraries). Here is what I have.

```
cast_data = pd.read_csv("cast.csv")
cast_data.replace(cast_data.replace(r"^\N*$", math.nan, regex=True))
```

Here's the error I'm getting, can someone explain why? thanks.

```
raise source.error("missing {")
re.error: missing { at position 3
```

Comment: Maybe this is happening because of your regex.
`df.replace(r"^\\N.*$", math.nan, regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

`\N` is the Unicode name escape, for example:

```
>>> '\N{tilde}'
'~'
```

So you just need to add another backslash there: `\\N`.

This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-35) for the `re` module:

> Most of the standard escapes supported by Python string literals are also accepted by the regular expression parser:
>
> ```
> \a      \b      \f      \n
> \N      \r      \t      \u
> \U      \v      \x      \
> ```
>
> ...
>
> *Changed in version 3.8:* The `'\N{name}'` escape sequence has been added. As in string literals, it expands to the named Unicode character (e.g. `'\N{EM DASH}'`).

Comment: thanks that solve my problem but now only the \N in the last row of the datasets are converted to math.nan the rest are still showing up as \N. Any idea why?

Comment: @blacklion I see you've asked a new question already. BTW, the title is almost the same, which is confusing, so you might want to give these two questions different titles to distinguish them. Like, you could rename this one, "Trying to replace values in a dataframe with regex, but getting 're.error: missing {' ". For tips on writing a good title, check out [ask].